# Argument of varying types?

Tags: processing

how do I make a argument of varying types?

I want to do `m.add(5)` or `m.add(float[][])`. How would I do that?

```java
void add(? n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
            data[i][j] += n;
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can provide two different function definitions. Such function overloading is possible in processing as long as either the number or the types of the arguments differ (as they would in your case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for something called **method overloading**. You can google that for a ton of results, but basically you'd want to define the function twice:

```
void add(float n){
  // do the thing
}

void add(float[][] n){
  // do the thing
}
```

In theory you could also take an `Object` parameter and then use the `instanceof` keyword to figure out what type was actually passed in, but that's a hackier approach.